# phpmyadmin error 403 - Forbidden rejected - It seems that the connection to server has been lost

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Since a few weeks I am getting errors within phpmyadmin, when I try to switch to the next result page, or if I use the search feature.

I get an red window within phpmyadmin telling me, that an error 403 happened. Errortext: Forbidden (rejected) - It seems that the connection to server has been lost. Please check your network connectivity and server status.

I have no mod_security module installed. It happens when I log in into phpmyadmin as DB-User and also happens as "root"-User.

Could not find any informations in mysql.err or in apache error.log.

What could cause this problem? I am using Apache/2.4.7, libmysql 5.5.58, PHP 5.5.9 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi, where you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Increase memory_limit to **memory_limit=2G** from **php.ini**

hope it will help works for me.

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score -3):

Found out, that the firewall caused the problem. When using a direct connection to phpmyadmin everything works fine!

Comment: Can you elaborate on that more? What do you mean by "a direct connection" to phpmyadmin"? By IP as opposed to hostname?

Comment: please explain "direct connection"